# How to emit twice the same block using `pug` template inheritance?

Tags: node.js, pug

Using `pug` template inheritance I am unable to emit twice the same block:

```
html
  body
    block hello
    p x
    block hello
```

```
extends layout.pug

block hello
  p Hello #{name}
```

With `pug` 2.0.0-beta6, I obtain:

```
<html><body><p>x</p><p>Hello Forbes</p></body></html>
```

Whereas I was expecting:

```
<html><body><p>Hello Forbes</p><p>x</p><p>Hello Forbes</p></body></html>
```

Is there a way to emit several times the same block using `pug` template inheritance? Or did I made some mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing blocks with mixins: mixins are reusable components that you can reuse multiple times, and it looks like you should be using a `mixin` here (since you want to reuse the same block multiple times). Blocks, on the other hand, are placeholders to be used for inheritance scenarios (see the docs on [the `block` element](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html)). I have never seen them being placed more than once in child templates, but I'm not entirely sure whether it is possible at all, either.